# Iterate Json object best way

Tags: javascript

I have Json object returned with the following properties/values

**Json Data Object:**

```
Apple: true
Banana: true
Cat: true
```

I am checking each property is true or false as following but i think its't the smart way.. do i have alternative to if/else considering properties could be upto 15

MyController:

```
servive.getObject(id).then(function (response){
    var _apple = response.data.Apple;
    var _banana = response.data.Banana;
    var _cat = response.data.Cat;

    if (_apple == true && _banana == true && _cat == true)
    {
        ----------
        ---------
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```
var obj = response.data,
    result = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a, b){ return a && obj[b]; }, true);

if (result){
  .
  .
  .
}
```

> The [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

.

> The [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) has to reduce it to a single
>   value.

Working example:

```js
var obj = {
  apple: true,
  banana: true,
  cat: true
};

function getResult(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a && obj[b];
  }, true);
}

console.log(getResult(obj));

obj = {
  apple: true,
  banana: true,
  cat: false
};

console.log(getResult(obj));
```

Comment: Can you bit explain this code? I am getting reference error "obj is not defined"...

Comment: Great, it works. but i have few questions: 1) When all true the result contain 1 (why it doesn't contain True) ... When any of the property value is false than result contains false instead 0... Is it as expected?

Comment: As far as I see it returns true or false, I've added a working example.

Comment: yes it works fine thanks a lot, I am still trying to understand this line of code reduce(function (a, b) { return a && obj[b]; }    // Here a refer to what.. is it Previous Value(default)? b refer to what (is it current value) and then what & how we are returning? what this line doing return a && obj[b]

Comment: a = previousValue, b = currentValue, see documentation in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce